# Can I use any version of Java SE with Java EE 8?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

With every new release of Java EE, there's a bunch of new improvements and additions to the technology stack that come under it. JSF, JPA, EJBs will all have different versions associated with this new release. (Java EE 8 - JSF 2.3, JSP2.3, JPA 2.2, EJBs 3.2)

Java SE platform is releasing new version of Java SE every 6 months or so. How does this change fit in with the Java EE?

For example, if I'm developing an application in Java EE 8 which Java SE(9,10,11,12) should I use?

**1. Can I use any version of Java SE with Java EE? (Java EE 8 + Java SE 11) or (Java EE 8 + Java SE 8) or (Java EE 8 + Java SE 10).**

How does Java EE handles the ever changing Java SE? Because there's specific version specified for every technology used in Java EE 8 like JSF 2.3, JSP2.3, JPA 2.2, EJBs 3.2 .

**2. Why isn't a specific version of Java SE used in Java EE to do the programming?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## JDK 8+ is required, but...

It actually depends on your [Java EE 8 vendor](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html).

[Java EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Enterprise_Edition) 8 (a.k.a. [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee)) has a few API elements that require JDK 8, so the definitive baseline is at least [JDK 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).

For instance, I use [Wildfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly) 16 (= Java EE 8) with [JDK 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_12) and it works flawlessly so far, though JDK 8 is required.

Other vendors like [Glassfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish), [Weblogic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server) might require different versions. Glassfish, for instance [doesn't work yet on JDK 9+](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/ee8-release-notes-3894362.html).

Comment: By java ee vendor do you mean the application server on which we deploy our project?

Comment: @lea Yes, that's exactly what I mean.